# Getting .Net Font information?

Tags: c#, .net, fonts, system.drawing

Is there a wrapper around the Win32 API for getting font information without actually instantiating an instance of the .NET Font class?

For example, some fonts do not have a regular style so I need to determine what styles are valid for a font without actually creating an instance of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about FontFamily.IsStyleAvailable? You'll still have to instantiate the FontFamily class though, and I don't know what exactly is involved in that, but maybe it's more light-weight than Font.

Comment: Yes this appears to be what was needed.